# jquery/javascript - running two functions from an onComplete property

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, handler

I'm using a plugin which has a property "`onComplete`".

So I set something like this "`onComplete: completeHandler`"

And it runs the function defined in:

```
function completeHandler()
```

I just need an additional one line of code that I need to run, is there a way to say to run two functions? Or is my best way to write another function called "`alternateCompleteHandler`" and at the end of that function call `completeHandler()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you're looking for:

```
onComplete: function(){
   function1();
   function2();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want two functions to be run simultaneously, Use this:

```
setTimeout(function1,1); 
setTimeout(function2,1);
```

If you want them to run after each other, do this:

```
onComplete: function() {completeHandler();alternateCompleteHandler();}
```

its called anonymous function.

Comment: Please note that you cannot actually have two functions be processed at the same time in Javascript.  The Javascript engine in the browser will simply be context switching between the two functions, or running one after the other.

Comment: As you cant have two functions (or thread or even processes) run at the same time on a single CPU anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the most flexible way is to create a new function. I think there are better options for naming it, though :)